# jquery $.ajax jsonp

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain, jsonp

```
$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    dataType : "jsonp",
    url : '/',
    data : {}
    success: function(obj){

    }
});
```

How can i use $.ajax dataType: jsonp  cross-domain to post data?

Comment: Since you aren't stating what kind of error you are encountering I can just point you to this: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ which should do what you want - but then again it's just a shorthand for what you have written.

Comment: post data?? can you clairfy..

Comment: See the docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ You need to specify a callback function in your url.

Comment: he wants to post POST request cross-domain

Comment: IE8 use XDomainRequest but maybe user is ie6

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinte...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible with simple jsonp. Read **[this](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2009/08/27/jquery-post-jsonp-and-cross-domain-requests/)**

Comment: not sure how this helps? it doesn't provide a solution, just says you can't do it.

Answer (score 38):

To answer your question instead of sending you to another link like above:

The **JS**:

```
$.ajax({
     type : "GET",
     dataType : "jsonp",
     url : "http://domainname.com/json.php?callback=?", // ?callback=?
     success: function(data){
           // do stuff with data
     }
});
```

The **PHP** could possibly look like this:

```
<?php
include('connect.php');
$sql = "SELECT id, name, items FROM tablename ORDER BY id ASC"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $rows[] = array(
            "id" => $row['id'], 
            "name" => $row['name'], 
            "items" => $row['items']);
}
$json = json_encode($rows);
$callback = $_GET['callback'];
echo $callback.'('. $json . ')';
?>
```

Setting the `dataType` to `jsonp` will allow jQuery to automatically add an extra `?callback=?` to the end of your `url` to specify the callback. If you specify your own like above it will use the `callback` name you are passing. If you need to specify a json callback name use the `jsonpCallback` property. Or you can add as a param to the data property. If you need more info, please visit the jQuery API Ajax: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/.

Don't forget to add the `;` on the result string.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! After looking at a dozen examples, this one finally got my code working!