# Is there a way to return JSON rendered by javascript through ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain

I have a situation that I have to run some javascript and get a response on a clients site from my site, and I'm trying to think of the best way to do this because of cross domain scripting security.
I have access to placing a snippet of code on a client page.
I can modify my own site as much as I want.

One option is to open the page up via an iframe have the snippet on their site run get the response and set a cookie that I can poll for to get the response from...yikes...

I have been thinking of different ways to do this, and I'm trying to get creative.  I'm a backend guy with a bit of javascript experience, but nothing having to deal with cross domain stuff.  Please I would appreciate any help.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You could use [JSONP](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/) in your situation.

Example with JQuery could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202603/jquery-ajax-jsonp)

Comment: JSONP will suit your purpose. You need to make change in the server to  support JSONP. Basically you have to wrap your JSON object as an argument to a callback function - this is JSONP. Let me know if you need more info

Answer (score 0):

with your snippet on the client side create the iframe dynamically - then  you will be in a clients domain sandbox and will be able to send a request to your site

Comment: http://ajaxian.com/archives/how-to-make-xmlhttprequest-calls-to-another-server-in-your-domain

Answer (score 0):

May be you can call a web service via ajax call and return JSON string by following way..

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "JSON.asmx/Getdata",
            data: {},
            contentType: "text/javascript; charset=utf-8",
            ContentLength: 15000,
            dataType: "text",
            async: true,
            // timeout:10000,
            success: function (msg) {
                asmxdata(msg);
                return false;
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError, request, error) {
                alert('xrs.status = ' + xhr.status + '\n' +
                            'thrown error = ' + thrownError + '\n' +
                             'xhr.statusText = ' + xhr.statusText + '\n' +
                            'request = ' + request + '\n' +
                            'error = ' + error);
                return false;

            }
        });
```

Then on success of the Web service call (i.e method asmxdata() in here) you can evaluate the JSON string into a JSON object by following way:

```
function asmxdata(data) {
var JObject = eval('(' + data + ');');
}
```

and assign values to controls

```
document.getElementById('lblfirstname').value = JObject.Table[i].FirstName;
```

If anything is unclear please Comment.