# jquery ajax jsonp: this page is accessing information that is not under its control

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

I am trying to resolve Jquery Cross Domain issues.

with the following code i get in IE "this page is accessing information that is not under its control.."

```
$.ajax({
    type: "Post",
    url: "http://Webbie/WS.asmx/TrackLink",
    data: params,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,
    cache: true,
    success: function (msg) {
       alert('success');
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
       alert('error')
    }
});
```

I am getting the IE message and once i approve i am reaching 'success' alert.

I tried to replace json to jsonp with the following code (just changed datatype from 'json' to 'jsonp')

```
$.ajax({
    type: "Post",
    url: "http://Webbie/WS.asmx/TrackLink",
    data: params,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "jsonp", // just added the p
    async: true,
    cache: true,
    success: function (msg) {
       alert('success');
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
       alert('error')
    }
});
```

With the above jsonp code i am getting error 500.

why am i getting error 500? what is the best alternative for cross domain issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

POST via simple JSONP is not possible.

Read the answers to this question:

[jquery $.ajax jsonp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202603/jquery-ajax-jsonp)