# How to do jsonp post on rails from another domain

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, post

I want to do a POST with jsonp to rails rest service from another domain. I am using the following code in JQuery to do that. I am always getting 400 bad request.

I am jsut specifying the type as "GET" as jsonp can only do GET. Event if I specify type as POST it will overwrite to GET.

- do I need to do something on rails side to allow this
- What is the other way i can do POST to rails rest api from a another domain

  ```
                  $.ajax({
                          type : "GET",
                          url : "http://domain.com/movies.json",
                          contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                          data : sData,                               
                          dataType : "jsonp",                             
                          processData : false,
                           beforeSend: function(xhr)   
                        {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Http-Method-Override", "POST");
                           },
                          success : function(oJSON) {
                              console.log("in success of jsonp block")

                          },
                          error : function(XMLHttpRequest, status, errorThrown) {
                              console.log("in failure jsonp block")



                          }
                      });
  ```

Comment: you say POST, and yet you are using GET as the type. What do you really want? a cross-domain JSON POST? Are you just saying jsonp because google said it's the only way to do a cross-domain request?

Comment: is there another way to do a post for cross domain. Please let me know. I am saying GET because JSONP always do GET there is no POST. Even if u specify post it overwrites to GET.

Comment: Have a look at some of the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202603/jquery-ajax-jsonp