# backbonejs collection.fetch error handler

Tags: backbone.js, error-handling, fetch

The following backbone collection.fetch code fires, errors for some reason and then jumps to the error handler (as expected), but I don't really know what the errorhandler params are. The model, xhr and options params are undefined when error fires. What am I doing wrong?

```
  var onErrorHandler = function(model, xhr, options) {
      alert(options);
  };

  that.collection = new MembersCollection([]); 
  that.collection.fetch({ success : onDataHandler, error: onErrorHandler, dataType: "jsonp" });
```

@muistooshort: I totally forgot about the js arguments, thanks for that tip.

Here is what I found...

```
Arguments[0] = looks like its just the letter "d"
Arguments[1] = is an object. Has readyState, responseText, status, statusText
Arguments[2] = is an object. Exactly the same as [1]
```

The status = 200 and text is "OK". The responseText is the exact JSON data I expected to receive from the PHP server model.

So I guess now the question is why is that collection.fetch method sending the success result to the error handler? I don't believe  the sequence of those handlers in the fetch callbacks matter. Does it?

Comment: Are you sure they're all `undefined`? You can always `console.log(arguments)` to see what exactly is being passed.

Comment: you're missing some of the required ajax options for a jsonp request. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202603/jquery-ajax-jsonp

Comment: @muistooshort: I totally forgot about the js arguments, thanks for that tip. Here is what I found...

Comment: No, the sequence of the fetch callbacks doesn't matter, just tested, same result. For some reason it appears that the success result is being returned to the error handler every time.

Comment: I think that first argument is supposed to have a populated "models" collection. I see a models array but it is 0 length so something isn't working right there either. The responseText has a couple models in JSON format. I'm very confused about what this collection.fetch method is doing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok I found the params signature for the fetch callbacks and the success/error handlers. Now that those are set correctly, the fetch is working as expected. This is working code...

```
  var onDataHandler = function(collection, response, options) {
      console.log('membersview fetch onedatahandler');
      that.render();
  };

  var onErrorHandler = function(collection, response, options) {
      console.log('membersview fetch onerrorhandler');
      alert(response.responseText);
  };

  that.collection = new MembersCollection([]); 
  that.collection.fetch({ success : onDataHandler, error: onErrorHandler });
```

Thank you guys for your replies. I greatly need/appreciate your advice :-)